# How to draw a rect in the middle of screen-Android development

Tags: android, canvas, view, window-managers

I'm a new student of android dev, I'm trying to draw a rect in the middle of the screen, below is my source code, but it won't draw anything on the canvas, can you help to explain how this could be? thanks.

```
public class CustomView extends Activity
{
private static final String TAG="CustomeView";


MyDrawView myDrawView;
//RulerView myRulerView;

Canvas canvas=new Canvas();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i(TAG, "Get Window manager");

    WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    //MyDrawView myDrawView=new MyDrawView(this);
    myDrawView=(MyDrawView)findViewById(R.id.myDrawView);

    myDrawView.screenX=metrics.widthPixels;
    myDrawView.screenY=metrics.heightPixels;
    Log.i(TAG, "myDrawView.screenX="+ myDrawView.screenX);
    Log.i(TAG, "myDrawView.screenY="+ myDrawView.screenY);

    //Draw Rect in the middle of screen
    Log.i(TAG, "DrawRect");

    myDrawView.drawRect(canvas);
}

}


public class MyDrawView extends View {
public float screenX;
public float screenY;

Rect r = new Rect((int)(screenX/2-50),(int)(screenY/2-50),(int)(screenX/2+50),(int)(screenY/2+50));

Paint paint = new Paint();

{
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2.5f);
    paint.setAlpha(100);
};


public MyDrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public MyDrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyDrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void drawRect(Canvas canvas){

    // Draw Rect
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw in the activity by just creating a Canvas. This must be done from the onDraw method of a view.

So, instead of creating the canvas from the activity, get the one from the onDraw method in your MyDrawView class.

Inside of the class you can use getMeasuredHeight and getMeasuredWidth to get the size of the current view and draw accordingly.

Not sure the purpose of your rectangle, but, if it's just for decoration purposes, it will probably be faster to create a drawable xml file and  put into an ImageView in the middle of your layout.